# Installing Sphinx (2.0.1.beta) --with-mysql fails

Tags: mysql, centos5, installation, sphinxsearch, sphinx

I am trying to install sphinx on my centOS 5.6 x64

if I do yum install sphinx I get only 0.9,9 version, and I'd like to install 2.0.1-beta

so I followed the instructions in their documentation and I downloaded source tarball and run

```
./configure --with-mysql
```

I am getting an error that cannot find mysql include files

so I found out I need to install mysql-deve (yum install mysql-devel) but as it turned out I already had it.

so I tried to locate my mysql include files and after some digging I found out how to get the info where it is located

```
$ mysql_config --include
```

so this gives me:

```
-I/usr/include/mysql
```

so I repeated the exercise like:

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local/sphinx --with-mysql=/usr/include/mysql/
```

wich gave me this:

> configure: error: invalid MySQL root directory '/usr/include/mysql';
>   neither bin/mysql_config, nor include/ and lib/ were found there

I tred without trailing slash too

so what am I to do?

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the configuration script need to know the prefix where MySQL is installed and in your case that's **/usr**, so you can use the following command:

```
./configure --with-mysql=/usr --with-mysql-includes=/usr/include/mysql
```

Also, you may need another devel packages, not only *mysql-devel*.

**EDIT:** BTW have you noticed that there's a 64bit RPM package of Sphinx 2.0.1-beta for RHEL/CentOS 5? It's on the [downloads](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/beta/) page.

Comment: Your suggestion gives me: ......
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files. :(

Comment: Are you sure that you have *mysql-devel* installed? I added more command line options to my answer above (and some additional information).

Comment: Yes I msut be really blind! I installed that rpm with no problems, it is working now! thanx